# Thresholding a pandas dataframe by column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have data collected from a sensor with 6 degrees-of-freedom and now I am trying to perform some plotting and eventual signal processing tasks on it.

I made a Pandas dataframe and am trying to threshold or clip my data set based on the column "Stamp" which is a timestamp value in seconds. So far I have created my dataframe:

```
headers = ["Stamp", "liny1", "linz1", "angy1", "angz1", "linx2", "liny2"]
df = pd.read_csv("Test2.csv", header=0, names = headers, delimiter = ';')
df
```

which gave me:

[image: head of dataframe]

I now wish to threshold the data until the 18 second mark since everything after is just noise. I tried using the threshold function in pandas but I'm not sure if I did it right. Can someone point out what my mistake is?

```
df_thresh = df.clip(lower=None, upper=18)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use `loc` to filter your data for under 19 seconds.

```
df.loc[df['Stamp'] < 19]  # Not sure what units 'Stamp' is in. Seconds?
```

For reference, this is what you are doing if you where to clip your data, which I do not believe you want:

```
>>> pd.Series(range(16,21)).clip_upper(18)
0    16
1    17
2    18
3    18
4    18
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Your suggestion worked out for me. However, I kept getting a key error so I fixed that by adding the encoding information and now it works fine. And yes, 'Stamp' is in seconds.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
np.random.seed(12)
headers = ["Stamp", "liny1", "linz1", "angy1", "angz1", "linx2", "liny2"]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(60,size=(5,7)), columns=headers)
print (df)
   Stamp  liny1  linz1  angy1  angz1  linx2  liny2
0     11     27      6     49      2      3      3
1     12     48     22     49     52      5     13
2     25     34     11     54     10      0     53
3     40     12     13     18     25     35     36
4     35     33     30     55     32     18     22

df1 = df[df['Stamp'] < 19]
print (df1)
   Stamp  liny1  linz1  angy1  angz1  linx2  liny2
0     11     27      6     49      2      3      3
1     12     48     22     49     52      5     13
```

Or [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df1 = df.query("Stamp < 19")
```

---

[`clip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html) replace all values higher as `18` to `18`:

```
df_thresh = df.clip(lower=None, upper=18) #df.clip_upper(18)
print (df_thresh)
   Stamp  liny1  linz1  angy1  angz1  linx2  liny2
0     11     18      6     18      2      3      3
1     12     18     18     18     18      5     13
2     18     18     11     18     10      0     18
3     18     12     13     18     18     18     18
4     18     18     18     18     18     18     18
```